# Is there a way to have controller property change when it is binded to ng-model of a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs

something like this

```
.directive('dropDown', [])
{
   scope:{
     //custom properties 
   }
})
```

some when something like this would get instantiated and

`<div ng-controller="sandbox">
       <input ng-model="selected">
</div>`

how would I get selected to get the selected property?

Comment: direction or directive?

Comment: you are not clear. make your vision clear and tell us what do you want and how?

Comment: sorry, it's directive - basically when I have costume directive with a custom scope object, I still want to bind the ng-molde="" to one of the properties in the controller ($scope) rather then directives scope - does that make sense? Sorry for being vague.

Comment: ngModel: "="  as an  isolated scope property should do the trick